# Read file in ruby getting output as spaces in character

Tags: ruby, file

I have stored variable output to the file through powershell script.
Ex: `7644511AAFCFBA6A0CC4706F3AA795BB86` stored in file.txt

After that i read the data from the file and stored it in the variables using ruby script.
when i print the variable it is printing the data with spaces in between characters.
Ex: `■7 6 4 4 5 1 1 A A F C F B A 6 A 0 C C 4 7 0 6 F 3 A A 7 9 5 B B 8 6 E D 5 3 3 0`

I want to store the data in a variable with out any spaces between characters.
I tried a lot, but could not find the solution.

Content in `file.txt` file:

```
7644511AAFCFBA6A0CC4706F3AA795BB86ED5330
```

**Ex1:**

```
File.open("c:\\file.txt") { |f| puts f.read }
```

**Ex2:**

```
txt = open("c:\\file.txt")
print txt.read
```

**Ex3:**

```
File.readlines("c:\\file.txt").each do |line| 
  var = line 
  puts var 
end
```

Please give me your valuable suggestions.

I am doing this in windows platform

Comment: Would you mind to share the code you use to read the file?

Comment: And your test file being read by your ruby script.

Comment: Looks like an UTF-16 encoding issue. These spaces could be null bytes and the leading `■` could be a BOM.

Comment: Actually i have used lot of methods to read file.

Comment: @sravanth try to create a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Ex1 . File.open("c:\\file.txt") { |f| 
puts f.read 
}

Ex2:     txt=open("c:\\file.txt")
print txt.read



Ex3.  File.readlines("c:\\file.txt").each do |line|
var=line
puts var
end

Comment: @sravanth don't post it as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: That does not make any sense i tried your all examples and they printed the output without any space.

Comment: @Mourad I am wondering, I am using it in windows server. But i could not get the proper output

Comment: @Stefan. Could you please let me know what is the UTF-16 issue and leading ■

Comment: @sravanth unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem. Upload your actual file (file.txt) somewhere and post a link.

Answer (score 1):

Its may be an issue with `file.txt` rather than your code. And as @stefan said its probably due to UTF-16 encoding of the file, whereas ruby uses the default encoding of your environment. For example if your environment (where you are getting this result - ie.. powershell) is set to UTF-8 ruby will read the file as a UTF-8 file.

You can manually set the encoding using: `File.read("file.txt", encoding: <encoding>)`. Where `<encoding>` is the type of file. I suggest looking at this may help understand the problem better. I also suggest you look at the encoding of `file.txt` to understand what its encoding is.

Comment: Thanks Lee-Jon.

When i create the file from powershell, the file has Unicode encoding.
But ruby has Ascii, so i changed encoding to Ascii while creating file thoriugh powershell
<some text> | Out-File -en ascii c:\\file.txt.

It is working fine